# c# How to check which line is selected listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I need suggestions how to see which line is selected in a Listbox (winforms).
So when I click a line in the listbox a messagebox will popup with the text: `You clicked line X` or `You selected line is X`

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: So you just mean MessageBox.Show("You selected line " + listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()); ?  Obviously arrays start at 0 so line "1" will be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you double-click the `ListBox` in the designer window, the default event handler will be created (which is `SelectedIndexChanged`), which fires each time a new item is selected in the `ListBox`.

Then you can use the `SelectedItem` property if the `ListBox` to get the value of the item that was just selected, and you can use the `SelectedIndex` property to get the `0`-based index of the item (add one to this value since most users think if the first item as `1` instead of `0`).

Putting this together, you can do:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"You clicked line {listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1}, " +
        $"which is: {listBox1.SelectedItem}", "ListBox Selection Changed");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("You clicked line "+ listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```